# Save text from file between two given characters and save the output to file?

Tags: linux, command-line, regex, grep, perl

I have a file with the following kind of text:

```
@ heading with some text
the.actual.text.of.choice
which.can.be.several.lines
in.length.with.no.pattern
+
more.text.that.i.want.to
remove.several.lines.long
```

I tried with the following:

```
perl -pe '^@ .* $+' input_file.txt > output_file.txt
```

which I read as: '@ at beginning of line, followed by any number of characters and ending with + at the end of the line'. But I got the following error:

```
syntax error at -e line 1, near "^"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Since I am quite new with regex, could you please tell me where I am wrong? And is there a way to do it directly with `grep`? Maybe with the `-f` or `-E` options?

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://superuser.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

`do{local $/; <STDIN>}` reads all input into one string.

`=~ /^@[^+]+\+/gm` matches string against regex (a line starting with `@`, followed by any char except `+`, ending with `+`).

`print $&` print the whole match.

```
cat input_file.txt | perl -e 'do{local $/; <STDIN>} =~ /^@[^+]+\+/gm; print $&' > output_file.txt
```